# Having Difficulty Building Stats Bot for Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to build a discord bot for my hockey league and so far it's running good, but I'm having difficulty keeping track of each players stats.

I've already tried using other's currency bots and changing them but I couldn't figure it out.

```
@bot.command()
async def forward(ctx, message):
  ID = message.author.id
  y = fwd.len()
  z = 0
  for x in fwd:
    z += 1
    if x == ID:
      None
    if z == y and x != ID:
      lid += 1

      fwd.append(ID)
      #Goals, Assists, Pass Percentage, Hits
      if a == 0:
        a = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        print("Using A")
      if b == 1:
        b = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        print("Using B")
      if c == 2:
        c = [0, 0, 0, 0]
      if d == 3:
        d = [0, 0, 0, 0]
      if e == 4:
        e = [0, 0, 0, 0]
      if f == 5:
        f = [0, 0, 0, 0]
      if g == 6:
        g = [0, 0, 0, 0]
      if h == 7:
        h = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I expect it to save the stats in a list where the lid var equals where they are in the list, making it easy to find and print out, but it is saying that message is a required argument although it is given.

Comment: If you can't figure it out, can y'all at least upvote it so that I can get the attention of someone who can help solve it?

Comment: How are you calling this command from discord?  You're probably not passing a `message` argument.  (And you don't need to, you get the message that called the command in `ctx.message`)